# JavaScript: Fade from one table body to another

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, fade

I am filling my table using AJAX, I get the data returned as a JSON and I want to update my table with the new data.

That's easy, and I achieve it doing this:

```
var output= "";

        for (var i = 0; i < content.flights.length; i++) {
            output+= "<tr><td>";
            output+= content.flights[i].id;
            output+= "</td></tr>";
        }
document.getElementById("flights").tBodies[0].innerHTML = output;
```

How can I fade between the two versions though? As in, when I have new data, how can I fade the text between the old and the new?

The basic requirement here is to add data in a nice way. If there is an even better solution, please don't hesitate to point me towards it!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can compare the two lists and add the new ones at the bottom if order doesn't matter. If you want to just load in another table entirely I'd build it like you do now, but transition by chaning the font to be fully transparent, load the new table and return to the normal transparency with a short fade.

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: @Kerwin Sneijders that sounds like a good idea, but it is gonna fade out all the way and then fade back in that way, rather than fading over.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can make a fade effect with css and fetching data from the server.

After you click on "Get new Data" at the bottom, a new request will be sent and the table will be reloaded

```js
const fetchData = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => {
    var output= "";

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        output+= "<tr><td>";
        output+= users[i].name;
        output+= "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("table").tBodies[0].innerHTML = output;

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("table").tBodies[0].classList.remove('fade-out'); 
    }, 400); // time for animation
})
}

document.getElementById('newDataBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("table").tBodies[0].classList.add('fade-out');
    fetchData();
});

fetchData();
```

```css
.t-body {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.t-body.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">

  <table id="table">
    <tbody class="t-body" id="tBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="newDataBtn">Get new data</button>

  
</div>
```